# Google Map view in emulator emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

I am running a simple android program to view a google map in android emulator.

Here my output screen of viewing google map in android emulator.i checked internet connection in browser emulator.its shows internet connection.but output couldnt load here.So How to load google map in emulator.how to check the setting in emulator
[image: Google Map View in android emulator]

Comment: how to locate the keystore in eclipse /home/ant000111/.android/debug.keystore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow all the steps required to generate the Maps Key and sign your app with the appropriate certificate?
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

**To use the classes of the Maps external library in your application, you need to:**

- Install the Google APIs add-on, as described in the Installing document. If you are using the Android SDK, you don't need to install the add-on — it's preinstalled in the SDK package.
- Set up a new Android project — or reconfigure an existing one — to build against the installed Google APIs add-on
- Set up an Android Virtual Device configuration that uses a the Google APIs add-on
  Add a uses-library element to your application's manifest file, to reference the Maps library.
- Use the Maps classes in your application
- Get a Maps API Key, so that your application can display data from the Google Maps service.
- Sign your application properly, using the certificate that matches your API Key.

Comment: Actually i go to that website and i just copy the md5 finger print key and getting the Maps key from google website.i think how to get the MD5 finger print key

Comment: @rajesh You must follow the steps as per docs to get correct output.

Comment: i followed all the steps.i think some problem getting md5 certificate i think..this is my confusion

Comment: other things are ok .i followed all the steps correctly.using google Api device in my emulator,putting permission in my android manifest file...

Comment: You can use keytool which comes along with JDK to generate one

Comment: how to get MD5 finger print certificate.actually i copy and paste the MD5 certificate key in google website

Comment: their website.i didnt understand that how to use keytool in ubuntu eclipse

Comment: in my eclipse path there is a keystore path /home/ant000111/.android/debug.keystore.how to use this keyttol in terminal.what is the procedure

Answer (score 0):

open eclipse path--click window-preferences-android-build path--/home/ant000111/.android/debug.keystore

open the terminal--cd /home/ant000111/.android/ copy the keytool and paste it. you get the MD5 certificate and put into the xml file and run the application in google api device..

```
 keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

(assuming you are running this in the directory where your debug keystore resides, which is ~/.android on Ubuntu)